# css not being applied in perl cgi script

Tags: css, perl, cgi, xampp

I am using Xampp to test my perl cgi scripts. When I open the cgi script the css does not seem to apply to the page. I have tried the exact same code in an html file and it works fine which suggests the html is linking to the correct place to find the CSS.

```
$self->{content}=<<HTML;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>$title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="../css/additional.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" >Bridge : $env </a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-upload"></i>upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-search"></i>Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i>Admin</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
</html>
HTML
```

Comment: What is the path the CGI script is requested with? What path did you test? (Not the physical path of the file system, but the path in the browser, please). Are you sure you don't want to use absolute paths to link resources?

Comment: The source code of the Perl doesn't matter. What matters is the generated HTML. Check the net tab of your browser's developer tools. Is the browser attempting to load the stylesheet? Is the URL it is attempting to load the one you expect? Are you getting a `200 OK` response from the server for the stylesheet?

Comment: @amon I thought using exact paths were bad practise. the browser path appears to be correct it is "localhost/xampp/cgi-bin/web/css/bootstrap.min.css and thats the correct path where the file is at.

Comment: @Quentin I'll have to check when i get back on the computer I was working on wasnt expecting such a speedy response. but when i was looking in the developer tools it wasnt picking up any of the css in bootstrap.min so maybe it wasnt attempted to load

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> localhost/xampp/cgi-bin/web/css/bootstrap.min.css

Your web server is probably configured to treat everything in `cgi-bin` as an executable.

CSS is not a programming language that the server can interpret, so it will likely be offering up a 500 error when you try to load it.

Don't keep static resources in `cgi-bin`.

Comment: In my case I had to take the static resources completely out of `cgi-bin` and chose to put them in `/var/www/html/web/css`.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it would be possible to test with http connection:
Something like: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.0.32/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">`
Here is my script (very very dirty):

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw(:standard);
print header;
print_hdetails();
print"<body data-spy=\"scroll\" data-target=\"\.bs-docs-sidebar\">\n";
print_navbar();
print_headerofpage();
print_mysidebar();
print_mybodycontent();
print end_html;

sub print_hdetails{
print <<FORMULE;
  <!DOCTYPE html>    
  <html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://192.168.0.32/cgi-bin/"><!--[if lte IE 6]></base><![endif]-->
    <title>bootstrapstyle page</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">   
    <!-- for Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.32/bootstrap/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.32/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://192.168.0.32/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!--link href="http://192.168.0.32/silverstripe/themes/bootstrap/css/myadded.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"-->    
    <!--link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://192.168.0.32/silverstripe/themes/bootstrap/images/favicon.ico" /-->    
    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/bootstrap/css/form.css?m=1373645318" /-->
  </head>

FORMULE

    }       
sub print_headerofpage {
    print <<CONTENT;
    <header class="jumbotron subhead" id="overview">
    <div class="container">    
    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <h2>bonjour!</h2><br>
    </p>
    </div>
    </header>
CONTENT

}
sub print_mysidebar{
    print <<MYSIDEBAR;
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
    <h6>Sidebar content</h6>
    <p>
    class=span2
    </p>
    <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav">
    <li><a href="#components"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> 1. Choose components</a></li>
    <li><a href="#plugins"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> 2. Select jQuery plugins</a></li>
    <li><a href="#variables"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> 3. Customize variables</a></li>
    <li><a href="#download"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> 4. Download</a></li>
    </ul> 
    </div>   
MYSIDEBAR

}
sub print_mybodycontent{
    print <<MYBODYCONTENT;
      <div class="span10">      
      <h1>Hello, world! </h1>
      <p>
        ici c'est le body content class=span10
      </p>
      <p>
      <h4>Le sourire, il fait plaisir a ceux qui vous aiment. Il emmerde ceux qui vous detestent. </h4>
      </p>          
      </div>    
MYBODYCONTENT

}

sub print_navbar  {
    print <<LANAVBAR;
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="brand" href="./index.html">Bootstrap</a>
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav">
<li class="">
<a href="./index.html">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="./getting-started.html">Get started</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="./scaffolding.html">Scaffolding</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="./base-css.html">Base CSS</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="./components.html">Components</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="./javascript.html">JavaScript</a>
</li>
<li class="active">
<a href="./customize.html">Customize</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
LANAVBAR

}
```

it works for me.